# How to deactivate animations in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-animation

I am trying to deactivate the Android's default animations, I tried do it by all ways I know, but it always return.

I am refering to the animations that shows when the activity change. I have added this in all my intents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), conf1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

At first It worked, but later five or six testing the animations began to be seen. I thought I have changed something, so I added this to all my activities in AndroidManifest.

```
android:windowAnimationStyle="@null"
```

Like with the intents, at first It worked, but now the animation are visibles again. Do you know any solution? I am doing something bad? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below line after startActivity

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

This will override the default device animation and do no animation. You can also give some custom animation like below

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems works perfectly, when I back to the last activity doesn't work, but for the moment it's ok!